# Upload images in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, image-upload

I'm new to Codeigniter and I'm having problem with image upload function. 
Error says - You did not select a file to upload. 
Can anyone check my code and tell me what to do?

**THIS IS MY CONTROLLER**

This is my Controller which processes data.

```
public function add_data() {
    $this->load->view('admin/header.php');

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'price', 'required');

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/add_view.php');
        $config['upload_path'] = './files/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('picture');
        $this->upload->data();

        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'info' => $this->input->post('info'),
            'gorod' => $this->input->post('gorod'),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
            'amount' => $this->input->post('amount'),
            'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
            'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
            'minbal' => $this->input->post('minbal'),
            'contacts' => $this->input->post('contacts'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'alias' => $this->input->post('alias'),
            'filename' => $this->input->post('picture')
        );
        $this->Adminmodel->add_record($data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/formnotsuccess');
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
 <form method="post" action="add_data" role="form" style="padding: 30px">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
        <label>Название университета</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" size="20">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
        <label>Информация об университете</label></br>
        <textarea id="textarea" name="info"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Город</label></br>
        <select class="form-control" id="gorod" name="gorod">
            <option value="Алматы">Алматы</option>
            <option value="Астана">Астана</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Стоимость обучения</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Количество студентов</label>
        <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Возраст университета</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Статус университета</label></br>
        <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
            <option value="Государственный">Государственный</option>
            <option value="Частный">Частный</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Минимальный балл для поступления</label>
        <input type="text" name="minbal" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Контактные данные</label>
        <textarea id="textarea2" name="contacts"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>E-mail</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Alias</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="alias" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Картинка заднего фона</label></br>
        <input type="file" name="picture" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Comment: TO upload file we use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form

[Read php file upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

> And Upload code should be like bellow. Its **easy to *track your errors***

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) # do_upload('picture');
{
    echo  $this->upload->display_errors();
}
else
{
    $data =  $this->upload->data();
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: thanks. it works. One more question, how to get filename and add that to database?

Comment: Try `$data['file_name']` and send that to model andd add update or insert function. Accept + vote if helps